# Allow login with user phone number in WooCommerce

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a WooCommerce website and Every customer has a Mobile number.
Now, I want to Replace All My WooCommerce website **usernames** With **their billing Phone numbers**. What can i do?
**We Get a user phone and send a verification code to him/her, and user logins without any password**. Login Like telegram messenger.
Now, new users register and login without any problem but the older users needs to replace their usernames with their billing phone numbers.

Can i run any Query in database or anything?

```
table: WP_Usermeta > billing_phone    to  Table:  WP_Users > user_login
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why do you want to replace if you have both? do you mean login with phone number ?

Comment: @Ash0ur: Yes. I want the customers logins with phone numbers. thx

Comment: You can't replace username by a user phone, so I have slightly change the title of your question. May be what you can do is to replace the fields label, if username value is replaceable with a number phone… But remember that username is not editable in Wordpress.

Comment: Hi  LoicTheAztec/ Its not a problem. we want to call a user with his phone number.
**We Get a user phone and send a verification code to him/her, and user logins without any password**. Login Like telegram messenger.

Comment: Now, new users register and logns without any problem but the older users needs to replace their usernames with their billing phone numbers.